# SSRS Tablix on Left side relocates tablix on right Why?

Tags: reporting-services

Using SSRS 2012

I have a tablix on the left side of the page which is tied to a dataset. When previewed the tablix will consume most of the left side of the page as it is designed to do. No problem so far.

I have 4 other tablix on the right side of the same page used just to create boxes and aligned text. I hope the ascii art will help visualize this. I hear that this type of tablix use is not standard and if that is really the problem I will revisit their use, but I like the alignment possibilities.

Here is a graphic representation of the issue:

Design mode:

```
|HEADER | |------|
| DATA  | | xxxx |
| DATA  | |------|
|-------|
          |------|
          | xxxx |
          |------|

          |------|
          | xxxx |
          |------|
```

When run in preview or exported using TIFF, PDF or Excel, I find that wherever the left tablix ends, all the tablix on the right side are pushed below it. Like this

Preview mode:

```
|-------| |------|
| xxxx  | | xxxx |
| xxxx  | |------|
| xxxx  |
| xxxx  |
| xxxx  |
| xxxx  |
| xxxx  |
| xxxx  |
|-------|
           |------|
           | xxxx |
           |------|

           |------|
           | xxxx |
           |------|
```

There are no overlaps, this renders the same in preview and when exported. I have moved the left tablix up and down and verified that the bottom right corner of the left tablix determines where the interference with the objects on the right side will occur.

Please help me understand what is going on here. I understand overlapping will mess things up but as I said there is none of that going on here. The left tablix Page break property is None, False,False

Enclosing everything in a rectangle does not fix this. It moves the entire page down and the tablix still affects formatting as it did before.

I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not have had any luck with this, but Rectangles are definitely the way to go here.

You say you enclosed everything in a Rectangle, but based on your description, you would need to enclose the three right tablixes in a Rectangle, not all four.

This way, the right three tablixes get rendered together inside the Rectangle, then the left tablix gets rendered and placed together with the Rectangle and its contents assuming they have the same vertical location - this should achieve your desired results.

The other thing to check is whether the right tablixes were placed in the Rectangle correctly - check the **Parent** property for each tablix to make sure that this has been updated from Body to the Rectangle as appropriate.

Comment: I did try enclosing the left side, and then the right side, and then the whole thing, then just the right Tablixs (Tablii ?). The result is that the entire rectangle and its contents gets moved down instead of only the one where the left tablix ends.

Comment: Ummm, well now, the PARENT parameter sure makes a difference. For  additional info I played around and found that textboxes and everything else are affected by the position of the the tablix on the left. Still poking at it but this looks like the right answer. Thank you.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is checking the **Location** -> **Top** value of the left tablix and the right Rectangle - they should be exactly the same. (edit) OK from your last comment maybe that was the issue - that's what I was trying to express when I said the "same vertical location" above.

Comment: I waited to long to edit my initial reply so it posted before I was ready. Your rectangle solution worked once I made sure of the Parent property. That was the missing bit that I assumed just happened when you created it. I wish I understood why that was needed, why should that Tablix relocate objects it is not anywhere near?

Comment: @Old.Fogie, I think the only answer is that it's by design; SSRS seems to assume that side-by-side items should be rendered together then everything else relative to them... Does it make sense in some cases? Sure. Others? Definitely not. Unfortunately I guess it depends on your needs at the time. I wish I had a better answer!

Comment: This seems to be a common topic. But the report looks like it should again - I guess I'll stop complaining :) Thanks again for the help.